# how to filter text based on checkbox value using angular filters?

Tags: angularjs

```
View By :
<input type="checkbox" name="filter" />All
<input type="checkbox" name="filter" />name
<input type="checkbox" name="filter" />type

<span class="displayphones">{{ phone | filter:? }}</span>
```

here i have 3 check boxes, by default it has to display all. while selecting the checkbox, it

should display the appropriate results but i dont know how to pass the checkbox value to filters without repeating ng-model like this

```
View By :
<input type="checkbox" name="filter" ng-model="all" />All
<input type="checkbox" name="filter" ng-model="name" />name
<input type="checkbox" name="filter" ng-model="type" />type

<span class="displayphones">{{ phone | filter:all:name:type }}</span>
```

is it possible to do this in some other way???

Comment: Why is having 3 ng-models a problem?  Normally, in Angular, each form element has its own ng-model.

Comment: actually having 3 ng-model is not my problem. i want to pass all of the ng-model values as an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the data-ng-true-value to accomplish what you want. It can even be used for checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="myCheckboxGroup" data-ng-true-value="1" /><br >
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="myCheckboxGroup" data-ng-true-value="2" /><br >
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="myCheckboxGroup" data-ng-true-value="3" /><br >

{{myCheckboxGroup}}
```

Here are the docs on it: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.checkbox

Comment: no in this way one value will be updated by other one. it will almost like radio buttons. i need some other way.

Comment: will it be possible to get all the values selected by the user with that single data-ng-model?

Comment: No, a data-ng-model is just a specific value, not an array.

Comment: Let's use input type text as an example of why this won't be possible. I have three of them each with the same ng-model. If i type in one it will update the other two right? I will not be able to get them to "join" into an array unless I specify the ng-model for each one of them as unique.

Comment: yes i know dat. thats y asked for some other way. there must be some way to do that.

Comment: Create your own custom filter that you can pass an object too and then you can have

`<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="myCheckboxGroup.all" data-ng-true-value="1" /><br >

<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="myCheckboxGroup.name" data-ng-true-value="2" /><br >

<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="myCheckboxGroup.type" data-ng-true-value="3" /><br >`

then in your filter:
`{{ phone | customFilter:myCheckboxGroup }}`

Comment: is it possible to define that ng-model value dynamically?? like this <div ng-repeat="e in eventtypes">{{ e }}<input  type="checkbox" ng-model="{{'filter.'+e}}" name="{{ e }}" /></div> i have to do in this way

Comment: Close:

`<div ng-repeat="e in eventtypes">{{ e }}<input type="checkbox" ng-model="{{filter[e]}}" name="{{ e }}" /></div> `

Answer (score 2):

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.filters = [ 
      {name: 'All',  selected: false},
      {name: 'name', selected: false},
      {name: 'type', selected: false}];    
}​
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.selected" name="filter">{{filter.name}}
   </div>
   debug: {{filters}}
   <br><span class="displayphones">{{ phone | customFilter:filters }}</span>
```

I don't know what your phone data looks like, so the filter implementation is left as an exercise for the reader:

```
myApp.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(phone, filters) {
       ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting it right is probably because you are not using the right UI element for your use case. The right UI element would be a radio input instead of a checkbox. A radio group is a toggle while a check box is not.

If you use a radio input the same is pretty easy to achieve :

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="filterType" value="All" />All
<input type="radio" ng-model="filterType" value="name" />name
<input type="radio" ng-model="filterType" value="type" />type

<span class="displayphones">{{ phone | filter:filterType }}</span>
```

That is it. Now you are good to go. Hope this helps.
If you really want to work with a checkbox then its a bit more complicated than this.